# Captcha is not showing in login page : Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and trying to implement captcha on the login page. I am following this package: https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha

I followed all the guidelines to install and configure it in config and blade. I have also placed the secret and site key in the config/captcha.php file.

I meant, I installed it, then I placed ServiceProvider and aliases in config file. Published the config file. Finally, placed the secret key and site key in published file.

I am working it on localhost. When I run it, it goes not show captcha and there is no js or server side error showing.

Am I missing anything?

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: did you `publish` it? how'd you display it? in the docs stated that you should init by `renderJs` then `display` it.

Comment: Can you please show your code for how you will display it in your login view page??

Comment: i think captcha will work on server only not in local server

Comment: I agree with @kunal, reCAPTCHA does work on localhost (the fact that  you can get the captcha-incorrect-sol error code shows that).

Comment: But @kunal "If you would like to use "localhost" for development, you must add it to the list of domains." This will only work if you access localhost using 127.0.0.1/... rather than localhost/....

Comment: @HirenGohel I have added recaptcha many times in website it should work only in server not working on localhost i use follow bootsrap validation in every website. i follow this linkonly :- http://formvalidation.io/addons/recaptcha2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "If you would like to use "localhost" for development, you must add it
>   to the list of domains."

This will only work if you access localhost using `127.0.0.1/...` rather than `localhost/....`

The original answer is preserved below.

According to [the reCAPTCHA Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/start):

> "By default, all keys work on "localhost" (or "127.0.0.1"), so you can
>   always develop and test on your local machine."

In other words, simply use the same key.